# Running Tests in Parallel in Night watch

Tags: nightwatch.js

Need some help in figuring out how to run tests in parallel.
Here is how the project is configured and the command I use to run a test.

On the terminal window in run the command - 'npm run test-qa' whoch actually call the 'package.json' which has a script tag to called 'test-qa'. 
Here is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-nightwatch": "^0.2.6",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.10",
    "json-parser": "^1.1.5",
    "json-stringify": "^1.0.0",
    "oracledb": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-nightwatch-plugin": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test-local": "eslint . && gulp local:e2e --compilers js:babel-core/register --require babel-polyfill",
    "test-dev": "eslint . && gulp dev:e2e --compilers js:babel-core/register --require babel-polyfill",
    ***"test-qa": "eslint . && gulp qa:e2e --compilers js:babel-core/register --require babel-polyfill --env local",***
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.20",
    "selenium-server-standalone-jar": "2.47.1"
  }
}
```

The test-qa tag from package.json, in turn, calls gulpfile.js to execute the actual task(qa:e2e) in this case. Here is my gulp file code :

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const nightwatch = require('gulp-nightwatch');

const eslint = require('gulp-eslint');

gulp.task('qa:e2e', function qaSpec() {
    process.env.seleniumon = 'qa';
    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(nightwatch({
            configFile: 'nightwatch.json',
            cliArgs: ['--env local', '--reporter html-reporter.js']
        }));
});

gulp.task('local:e2e', function localSpec() {
    process.env.seleniumon = 'local';
    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(nightwatch({
            configFile: 'nightwatch.json',
            cliArgs: ['--env local', '', '--reporter html-reporter.js']
        }));
});

gulp.task('dev:e2e', function devSpec() {
    process.env.seleniumon = 'dev';
    return gulp.src('')
        .pipe(nightwatch({
            configFile: 'nightwatch.json',
            cliArgs: ['--env local', '--reporter html-reporter.js']
        }));
});

gulp.task('lint', function srcSpec() {
    return gulp.src(['**/*.js', '!node_modules/**'])
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});

gulp.task('default', ['lint']);
```

the qa:e2e task from gulpfile.js now calls nightwatch.json file to get settings and continue with the execution. Here is my nightwatch.json file:

```
{
  "src_folders": ["tests"],
  "output_folder": "reports",
  "custom_commands_path": [ "commons/util", "commons/up", "commons/searchPane", "commons/EditorValidations", "commons/model"],
  "custom_assertions_path": "",
  "page_objects_path": ["pages/admin", "pages/UP", "pages/searchPane", "pages/EditorValidations/CMO", "pages/EditorValidations/CPO", "pages/EditorValidations/GMO", "pages/EditorValidations/GPO", "pages/model"],
  "globals_path": "",

  "selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "./node_modules/selenium-server-standalone-jar/jar/selenium-server-standalone-2.47.1.jar",
    "host" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "drivers/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.ie.driver" : ""
    }
  },

  "test_settings": {
    "chrome": {
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "selenium_host": "selenium-hub.nikedev.com",
      "skip_testcases_on_fail": true,
      "end_session_on_fail":false,
      "globals": {
        "platform": "desktop"
      },
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true,
        "on_failure": true,
        "on_error": true,
        "path": "screenshots/chrome"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },
    "local": {
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "selenium_host": "127.0.0.1",
      "skip_testcases_on_fail": true,
      "end_session_on_fail":false,
      "globals": {
        "platform": "desktop"
      },
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true,
        "on_failure": true,
        "on_error": true,
        "path": "screenshots/chrome"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This setup is able to execute seamlessly.
I wanted to run test cases parallel and for the I added the following line to my nightwatch.json after "global_path"
  "test_workers" : {"enabled" : true, "workers" : "auto"},

After this configuration change the tests never initiated with an error ' throw new Error('Invalid testing environment specified: ' + envs[i]);' even though my gulp file has mention for the environment we want it to run. 
cliArgs: ['--env local', '--reporter html-reporter.js']

Can someone help me understand what changes do I need to make to run the test cases parallel?

Answer (score 0):

The `workers` option configures how many child processes can run concurrently.
    •   "auto" - determined by number of CPUs e.g. 4 CPUs means 4 workers
    •   {number} - specifies an exact number of workers
Test concurrency is done at the file level. Each test file will fill a test worker slot. Individual tests/steps in a test file will not run concurrently.
Version 0.9 brings improved support for displaying output when running tests in parallel. recommend setting `detailed_output` to `false` in your test settings for improved output readability.

Refer to this link:

> https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch-docs/blob/master/guide/running-tests/run-parallel.md